# Edited Question/Answer. Is there an editing history on per-post basis?

Tags: support

I frequently encounter situations where someone has edited my question/answer. How do I know what has been edited?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click on the link that says something like:

> edited 21 minutes ago

Then this will take you to a page that will show you what the edits on your question or answer are.

I should also point out that having your question edited is not an indication of a poor question - it is part of the culture of stackexchange to allow people to edit questions and answers to produce higher quality resources for other people to use.

Comment: Thank you so much.